# Cross-sheet search and conditional replace

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am a casual Excel user, familiar with basic cell formulas and a few of the built-in functions, but have no idea how to approach this problem.
I've been given a workbook with two sheets. The first sheet has over 10K rows of data across a bunch of columns. Columns D, G, and H are of interest.

Columns G and H each have 3-character symbols, treated as a pair, so for example, G12, and H12, G56 and H56. The symbols are not unique, but the pairs are. Column D contains the same word, TEST. So we have something like this:

```
--D--   --G--   --H--  
TEST    ABC     LMN  
TEST    ABC     XYZ  
TEST    GHI     LMN  
TEST    JKL     QRS  
TEST    LMN     JKM  
TEST    LMN     XYZ  
TEST    UVW     AMB
```

The second sheet has about 2800 rows of two columns A and B, containing the same type of 3-character symbol pairs. They are not ordered, but we do know that every pair on Sheet 2 is somewhere in Sheet 1, e.g.

```
--A--   --B--  
GHI     LMN  
UVW     AMB  
ABC     XYZ  
LMN     XYZ
```

For each symbol pair on Sheet 1, I need to determine if that pair is on Sheet 2 and, if so, the corresponding TEST in column D needs to be changed to DONE. So the result would be:

```
--D--   --G--   --H--    
TEST    ABC     LMN  
DONE    ABC     XYZ  
DONE    GHI     LMN  
TEST    JKL     QRS  
TEST    LMN     JKM  
DONE    LMN     XYZ  
DONE    UVW     AMB
```

Does anyone know of a fairly straightforward way to do this, maybe with built-in Excel functions? This is a one-time thing, so I don't need anything too fancy or "future-proof.
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you can use a formula like this:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((--(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4=Sheet1!$E1&Sheet1!$F1)))>0,"Done","Test")`
```

[image: test to see if match exists]

You'll need to change `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` to your actual sheet names, as well as expand the range of `$A$1:$A$4` and `$B$1:$B$4` to match your actual values.

What this formula is essentially doing is concatenating (i.e. combining) two columns of data (`Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4` and `Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4`) and looking for a concatenated value (`Sheet1!$E1` and `Sheet1!$F1`). If it finds it, the formula returns **TRUE**; otherwise, it returns **FALSE**.

***However***, you must be sure to put the `--` in so that it converts the **TRUE**/**FALSE** to **1**/**0**, respectively. Since `SUMPRODUCT` can't recognize strings, it needs number in order to evaluate. By then wrapping `SUMPRODUCT` up in an `IF` function, you are able to return the requested value of **Done** where appropriate.

---

**EDIT:**

As @CallumDA pointed out, you can also accomplish this with the following formula:

`=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,Sheet1!$E1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4,Sheet1!$F1)>0,"Done","Test")`

Both formulas will do the exact same thing (which is the cool part of Excel!), so either should work for your needs. I agree that the `COUNTIFS` looks a little friendlier, but I believe it's also worthwhile to understand how the `SUMPRODUCT` formula works, if only for future knowledge.

Comment: Wouldn’t COUNTIFS be more intuitive than SUMPRODUCT in this case?

Comment: It's possible that `COUNTIFS` would work in this situation, but my proposed answer uses `SUMPRODUCT` instead. You're welcome to post a solution using `COUNTIFS`, though. (This was in no way intended to sound rude)

Comment: The only reason I suggested it, rather than posted it, is because you are using `SUMPRODUCT` *exactly* like a `COUNTIF`. For example, `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10=5))` is the same as `COUNTIF(A1:A10,5)`

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, @CallumDA. I went ahead and edited my post to show the alternative formula. At the time of my posting yesterday, getting the `COUNTIFS` to work for me just wasn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay using VBA, then this should work:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    ' move data into a multi-dimensional array
    Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant
    arr1 = ws1.Range("G1:H" & lastRow(ws1, "G")).Value
    arr2 = ws2.Range("A1:B" & lastRow(ws2)).Value
    
    Dim i As Long, x As Long

    'loop the arrays for matches
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        For x = 1 To UBound(arr2)
            If arr1(i, 1) = arr2(x, 1) And arr1(i, 2) = arr2(x, 2) Then
                ws1.Cells(i, "D").Value = "DONE"
            End If
        Next x
    Next i

End Sub

Function lastRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional col As Variant = 1) As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

You can place the columns of data into a separate array for each sheet, then loop the arrays. `i` will also determine the line number, so it's easy to write a value to the "D" column.

---

If you are unfamiliar with VBA, read on:

> ***How do I access the VBE?***
> You can gain access to VBE by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> while you are inside your workbook.
>
> ***Okay, So I have the VBE open. Now how do I apply this Sub/UDF?***
> In the left pane you will see your workbook object modules. This is called the **Project Explorer**. You will need to create a new module, which you can do by `right-clicking inside the Project Explorer > Insert > Module`:
>
> [image]
>
> Now you can paste the Sub/UDF to this new module and you are all set!

Comment: @K.Davis Thank you for the detailed answer. I used the other solution for my problem, but will still try yours as a learning exercise!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for these solutions @TotsieMae and @CallumDA. I used the alternative formula with COUNTIFS and it worked perfectly after I made a minor change.

In order to propagate the formula down the entire Column D, the Sheet 1 cell references could not be absolute because they needed to increment at each row to use the correct pair of symbols. The final formula I used was:

Cell D1 =IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,Sheet1!E1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4,Sheet1!F1)>0,"Done","Test")

Then, propagating the formula down the column leads to:
Cell D2   =IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,Sheet1!E2,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4,Sheet1!F2)>0,"Done","Test")
Cell D3 =IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,Sheet1!E3,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$4,Sheet1!F3)>0,"Done","Test")
etc